# Can you execute chdk scripts externally via USB?

Tags: lua, camera, usb, chdk

I have been tinkering around with CHDK (canon hack development kit). I have been able to run chdk via SD card on my powershot g12 and even been able to run a script on it.

My interest lies more in controlling this externally via a USB cable. For starters I want to try controlling it from the computer, then maybe another device.

I have been to the CHDK website http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK and peeked around their forum as well but have not seen any mention of external execution.

Comment: I want to do the same(control G12 from computer using USB cable), did you have any luck doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  There are two approaches I've used with some success.

1.) I can control my Powershot G9 using CHDKPTP (https://app.assembla.com/spaces/chdkptp/wiki).  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and the r735 binary from the website.  The GUI lets you control the camera and run scripts.  This approach should work for any camera that CHDK supports.  (There is also a python binding for CHDKPTP, although I haven't managed to successfully build it yet.)

2.) Another approach is to use gphoto2, if your camera is supported by gphoto2. (NOTE:  It doesn't look like the G12 is supported by gphoto2, but I'm including it here in case it's useful to others)  On the G9, CHDK adds a property chdk_script to the available options in gphoto2.  Then scripts should be runnable with

gphoto2 --set-config chdk_script="scriptname"

The gphoto2 approach is demonstrated here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_42jd9tGF0)